# RTMP Stream Input to an OpenTok session

Tags: opentok, tokbox

So I've created a streaming app in my community website using OpenTok.  It's really great, but there are a few use cases where some of my community currently stream via YouTube and have a setup that uses RTMP.  They don't necessarily want to use YouTube, but have invested in hardware and software that streams using RTMP.  Is there a way to set OpenTok up so that it can take RTPM as an input and convert it to a Stream?

(I know that OpenTok can broadcast to RTMP - I'm not interested in output - I need RTMP as an input)

Answer (score 5):

Tokbox developer here

There is no REST API call to do this. You would have to do it programatically, as follows:

You can pipe a RTMP receiver with the Linux SDK (beta) or one of the officials SDK (ios, android, windows), using the custom audio and video capturer.

The idea is the following:
---> RTMP Stream --> [ RTMP receiver & media decoder ] --> Raw media --> 
[ ios/android/windows/linux SDK ] --> [ Opentok ]

If you want to get the linux SDK, please email support@tokbox.com

Comment: Would there be a delay? I am looking for a similiar solution, we are using OBS software for live streaming that can output the stream to the rtmp server. And we need to play it as a video output of a publisher.

Comment: Only one way to find out...  I guess there would be some lag, but one of the things I was greatly impressed with Tokbox was the lack of lack.  I've used OBS in the past with YouTube and it was very laggy...  it may just depend on what your needs are.  For a livestream where the only publisher is via RTMP this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I'm thinking of cooking something up with https://github.com/sergey-dryabzhinsky/nginx-rtmp-module - but it may take a bit of figuring out ;-)

Comment: I'm starting to look into this further.  Is using headless chrome a possibility?  RTMP Receiver pipe as webcam to headless chrome on the server?

Comment: I'm currently stuck getting the linux sdk to work on a virtual server: https://github.com/opentok/opentok-linux-sdk-samples/issues/4